# Unable to build project with both Firebase and Mapbox

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, mapbox

I have created a location-based game using the Mapbox SDK in Unity 2018.2.1f1, and it has been able to build just fine. My goal was to add database functionality to my project by using Firebase, to store GPS coordinates online.

I followed the official tutorial for setting up Firebase in a Unity project. When this was completed, a window popped up saying "Resolving Android Dependencies", which took about half an hour.

Since then, I have been unable to build to my Android device. I receive 96 gradle build error, and the one at the top is:

```
> No toolchains found in the NDK toolchains folder for ABI with prefix: 
mips64el-linux-android"
```

I reverted the project to its pre-Firebase version, and it was still unable to build, as if something in the Android build tools had been changed.

Next, I tried an entirely different version of Unity, and installed a fresh install of Unity 2019.2.9f1. I opted to use this version of Unity's in-build Android SDK and NDK. I reverted my project back to the last known working version (pre-Firebase), ported it to the new version of Unity, and completed a successful build to my device before moving on.

Then I followed the appropriate steps to add Firebase to my project again, and the same exact pop-up windows appeared in Unity, claiming that it detected "obsolete files" that it wished to delete (this time I said no), and then it performed the same "Resolving Android Dependencies" process.

Once this process was complete, I made no other changes, and tried to build again. It failed, and I received the same 96 gradle build errors. This confirms this error as repeatable on two different versions of Unity.

I believe this has something to do with conflicting dependencies between Mapbox and Firebase. Has anyone encountered this issue, or successfully been able to use these two things together in a project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the baseline problem is that something is telling the Android build process to generate project files for the MIPS architecture. This architecture was removed from the official NDK in r17 (see [this link](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis#sa) for supported architectures). I'm not sure if Unity ever supported it, but it's not in the current version:
[image: Target Architectures screenshot showing only ARM and x86]

I do not know how MapBox is packaged and shipped, so I don't exactly know what postprocessing hooks might be conflicting between that and Firebase. I'll try to give you some steps forward though.

First, make sure you have the latest SDK from [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity) and [MapBox](https://www.mapbox.com/unity/). Also, when it asks to delete obsolete files, say yes. The Play Services Resolver should only prompt this for files that it tracks (and the Firebase plugin ships in a state where this is expected).

If that doesn't help, look for a mips folder included in your Unity project (probably something like libs/mips or jnilibs/mips). Hopefully deleting these will fix the issue.

If the above doesn't work or is non-actionable, try using a mainTemplate.gradle file:
[image: Screenshot of Settings for Android showing Custom Gradle Template under Publishing Settings, Build]

If you follow the instructions I wrote up [here](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-manage-your-native-ios-and-android-dependencies-in-unity-like-firebase-921659843aef) to instruct the Play Services Resolver to patch your mainTemplate.gradle file:
[image: Patch mainTemplate.gradle checked]

You can double check your ABI filters directly in the file. By default it shows:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters **ABIFILTERS**
}
```

to match what you've selected in Unity. But you can use this to double check that mips64 isn't included via some other process.

Unfortunately I don't know what else to suggest if neither of the above options work. In that case I'd suggest posting a bit more of the error you're getting. If you can reproduce the error you're having with one of the [Firebase sample projects](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity), you can file an issue on that [issue tracker directly](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues). Finally, if you don't get an answer here and you do think that it's Firebase related, you can contact the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as well.

I hope something in my post helps!

--Patrick

Comment: Thank you for this in-depth reply! Sadly since this is for a school project that has already been turned in, I will not have time to go back and check the effectiveness of this solution until after the semester is over. For now, I will mark your answer as correct.